# What events are triggered for PV/PVC and from where?

Tags: events, kubernetes, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

`kubectl get events` list the events for the K8s objects.
From where the events are triggered for PV/PVC actually ?
There is a list of volume events
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/nodes/clusters/nodes-containers-events.html
but it does not identifies that which events are for which resource ?

Answer (score 3):

Let`s start from what exactly is an Kubernetes event. Those are object that provide insight into what is happening inside a cluster, such as what decisions were made by scheduler or why some pods were evicted from the node. Those API objects are persisted in etcd.

You can read more about them [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/events-stackdriver/#:%7E:text=Kubernetes%20events%20are%20objects%20that,were%20evicted%20from%20the%20node).
There is also an excellent tutorial about Kubernetes events which you may find [here](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-events-explained).

---

There are couple of ways to view/fetch more detailed events from Kubernetes:

Use `kubectl get events -o wide`. This will give you information about `object`, `subobject` and `source` of the event. Here`s an example:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON                  OBJECT                            SUBOBJECT                         SOURCE                                                          MESSAGE

<unknown>   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/web-1                                                           default-scheduler                                               running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "web-1": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

6m2s        Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded   persistentvolumeclaim/www-web-1                                     k8s.io/minikube-hostpath 2481b4d6-0d2c-11eb-899d-02423db39261   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-a56b3f35-e7ac-4370-8fda-27342894908d

6m2s        Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded   persistentvolumeclaim/www-web-1                                     k8s.io/minikube-hostpath 2481b4d6-0d2c-11eb-899d-02423db39261   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-a56b3f35-e7ac-4370-8fda-27342894908d
```

Use `kubectl get events --output json` will give you list of the event in `json` format containing other details such as `selflink`.

```
        ---
                "apiVersion": "v1",
        "count": 1,
        "eventTime": null,
        "firstTimestamp": "2020-10-13T12:07:17Z",
        "involvedObject": {
        ---  
        "kind": "Event",
        "lastTimestamp": "2020-10-13T12:07:17Z",
        "message": "Created container nginx",
        "metadata": {       
        ---
```

`Selflink` can be used to determine the the API location from where the data is being fetched.

We can take as an example  `/api/v1/namespaces/default/events/` and fetch the data from API server using `kubectl proxy`:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 & curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/events/
```

Using all those information you can narrow down to a specific details from the underlying object using `field-selector`:

```
    kubectl get events --field-selector type=!Normal
    or
    kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.kind=PersistentVolumeClaim
    
    LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON                  OBJECT                            MESSAGE
    44m         Normal   ExternalProvisioning    persistentvolumeclaim/www-web-0   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
    44m         Normal   Provisioning            persistentvolumeclaim/www-web-0   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/www-web-0"
    44m         Normal   ProvisioningSucceeded   persistentvolumeclaim/www-web-0   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-815beb0a-b5f9-4b27-94ce-d21f2be728d5
```

Please also remember that all the information provided by `kubectl events` are the same ones from the `kubectl describe <ojbect>`.

Lastly, if you look carefully into the [event.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/volume/events/event.go#L20) code you may see all the events reference for volumes. If you compare those with the `Table 13. Volumes` you can see that they are almost the same (execpt for `WaitForPodScheduled` and  `ExternalExpanding`)

This means that Openshift provided an aggregated set of information about possible events from different kubernetes that may  occur in the cluster.